# Windows 10 VM (Virtualbox) hang on Ubuntu 18.04 Hostsytem

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Running Windows 10 in a VM does not work on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 with Virtualbox 5 / 6.

One solution was (only tested on Ubuntu 18.04.2 with VBox 5.2.18):

**Force "KVM" as paravirtualisation:**

*Settings* -> *System* -> *Performance* -> *paravirtualisation* = **KVM**

In my case windows 10 hang at booting. This had fixed it.

[image]

As there are may hints not working I post that solution here.
I hope it may help you.

Does not help:

- disable USB controler
- set paravirtualisation to "none"

Comment: Instead of putting solved in the title, you should divide up your question here as a question of it hanging on you, then writing your own answer of how you solved it.  Then in about 2 days you can select your own answer as the best.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

One solution was (only tested on Ubuntu 18.04.2 with VBox 5.2.18):

**Force "KVM" as paravirtualisation:**

Settings -> System -> Performance -> paravirtualisation = **KVM**

In my case windows 10 hang at booting.

This fixed my problem:

[image]